# Comma separate strings in R column without splitting it into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to separate comma separated strings in the R dataframe given below. I have also given how the output df would look like. My code below only partially does the job as it creates lists out of each row in the column. 
How should I do this?

```
Df1:

Fruits
"Apple, Mango, papaya"  
"Apple, Mango"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
"Avocado"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
"Papaya, Raspberry, Strawberry, Blueberry" 

Desired Output df:

Fruits
"Apple", "Mango", "papaya"  
"Apple", "Mango"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
"Avocado"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
"Papaya", "Raspberry", "Strawberry", "Blueberry"
```

My code

```
Df1$Fruits <- strsplit(Df1$Fruits, ",")
```

Here's the output for this:

```
Fruits
c("Apple", "Mango", "papaya")  
c("Apple", "Mango")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
"Avocado"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
c("Papaya", "Raspberry", "Strawberry", "Blueberry")
```

How should I unlist these strings and get them in the desired format?

Comment: You shouldn't `unlist`.  It is a `list` of `vector`s which can be extracted with `[[` or `$`  Having said that it is not clear about the desired format.

Comment: The desired output is unclear. A data.frame in R has to have the same number of columns in each row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626038/9699371

Comment: Hi, my desired output has single column just as the primary df. But in each cell, the strings are separate and are extractable versus in df1, where each comma separated string is read as a single string because of the quotes covering the three comma separated strings. I hope it makes sense. The whole idea is to reach each of these strings separated by commas and match it against a different df. But when I do the matching, the three strings in a cell are read as one because of the quotes.

Comment: Do you want to store them as list then? `df$fruits1 <- strsplit(df$fruits, ",")` ? So you can access them individually `df$fruits1[[1]][1]` , `df$fruits1[[1]][2]` etc.

Comment: @RonakShah, I have about a million of such rows, how should I access each of these strings in a row and then go about doing that for several rows?

Comment: `my desired output has single column just as the primary df. But in each cell, the strings are separate and are extractable`  That is exactlythe behavior of a the list

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with `tidyr::separate` and data manipulation.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
newdf <- df %>% 
  tidyr::separate(fruits, paste0('col', c(1:4)), sep = ',', remove = T)

Fruits_1 <- newdf %>% 
  dplyr::select(col1) %>% 
  na.omit()
Fruits_2 <- newdf %>% 
  dplyr::select(col2) %>% 
  na.omit()
Fruits_3 <- newdf %>% 
  dplyr::select(col3) %>% 
  na.omit()
Fruits_4 <- newdf %>% 
  dplyr::select(col4) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

- Data:

```
df <- data.frame(fruits = c("Apple, Mango, papaya",
                            "Apple, Mango", "Avocado",
                            "Papaya, Raspberry, Strawberry, Blueberry"))
```

[R: Splitting one column (different lengths) into new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618241/r-splitting-one-column-different-lengths-into-new-columns)

Comment: my original dataframe has more than four strings combined together in certain rows, count of strings may go upto 30. How would you suggest I do this in that case?

Comment: Realize that what you are doing is a new question.